# Multiple select ng-options group by not indenting until collection is modified

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a dual pane multiple selection to shuffle objects between them, filtering from one pane to another. Everything is working just fine except for one small problem. When I load in the left selection pane, I have the options grouped, but they line up under their group title and don't indent. When I modify the underlying array and the watched collection updates, the options update. At this point, some of the options indent properly, but not necessarily all of them.

I've replicated some of the behavior in a simpler form in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/birdrock/uygbphwr/) to help illustrate this. Click the button and observe the select list indentation. I'm perplexed at this point, so I'm hoping someone out there can help me out. Thanks for any and all input!

http://jsfiddle.net/birdrock/uygbphwr/

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
<div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
<fieldset>
    <select 
        ng-options="p.first + ' ' + p.last for p in people"
        multiple="multiple" size="10"
        ng-model="selectedPerson"></select>
    <select
        ng-options="p.first + ' ' + p.last group by p.actor for p in people"
        multiple="multiple" size="10"
        ng-model="selectedPerson"></select>
    {{ selectedPerson }}
</fieldset>

<input type="button" value="Delete Actor" ng-click="deletePerson()">
</div>
```

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.people = [
        {...}
    ];

    $scope.deletePerson = function() {
        $scope.people.splice(0,1);
    }

});
```

Edit: After checking other browsers, it appears it is only a problem with Chrome Canary. Standard Chrome, Firefox, and Safari display correctly.

Comment: By Some of the options do you mean the group header does not intend as well as options under the group?

Comment: When it loads in, my understanding is that angularjs is effectively stuffing them under optgroups based on certain criteria. When this is done normally in html, the selections are indented relative to their optgroup. In this case, it isn't indenting the options until the underlying array is changed. In the fiddle, you'll notice the options pop over into the proper position when you click the button.

Comment: Your fiddle seems to work fine in Chrome. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @runTarm I should have checked other browsers before posting. I'm running Chrome Canary Version 38.0.2117.2 canary (64-bit) on OS X. On standard Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, it works fine. I'm not sure how I can go about submitting a proper bug report for this, as it seems really obscure.